# Does aircrack-ng support my wifi adapter?

Tags: aircrack-ng

I am using aircrack-ng 1.2 rc4 on windows 7. Is there a command to ask airodump-ng which of my wifi adapters it recognizes ?

I tried `airodump-ng wlan0` and received `Adapter <wlan0> not supported`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an RTL8187 based adapter or an Alfa AWUS036AC - Both these realtek based USB adapters have been the best I have used. Some Atheros chipsets work but I always get poor range when using those, but not the realtek.

Another point is that Windows does a very, very poor job with aircrack-ng. Get hold of the Kali linux distribution and install - Everything is installed ready for you to start experimenting.

Comment: I am not going to buy a new adapter at this point. AFAIK my chipset is BCM43224, but i cant find a list of supported adapters at www.aircrack-ng.org for comparison.

Comment: https://www.2600index.info/Links/26/3/www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php%3Fid=compatibility_drivers.html It has a broadcom listed but isn't fully compatible.

Comment: so if I get to linux it should work, interesting